# Copy files from a directory to any USB using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, usb

I have written a  shell script which has a line as follows:

```
cp -r ~/home/usr/Application/ /media/sid/462F-0222
```

How ever the problem is **/media/sid/462F-0222**. This is because, it is just specific path to USB which I plug always. It will be different path if I plug in some other USB.

So what I am trying to do it, how to rewrite this script, or at least how can I mount **any** USB, copy files to that and unmount them using shell scripting.

The idea is to run this script on any Ubuntu machines. The approach of listing the mounted devices may not work if I am right as we can not list --> Go to a varying USB mount path it displays everytime and mount.

Any help/ suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: You could run `mount` before plugging in the USB stick, then tell the user to plug it in, and then run `mount` again afterwards and see what is different :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can give a partition a specific mount point by specifying it either in `mount`:

```
mount [...] device_uuid /path/to/mount/point
```

or in `fstab`:

```
UUID=device_uuid /path/to/mount/point [...]
```

To figure out what to put in `fstab`, have a look at what `mount | grep /media/sid/[...]` prints.

Comment: I guess the problem itself is /path/to/device right? Like I can not make a standard such path ?

Answer (score 0):

Shell Script for copying files/directory to USB

Prompt, you may not need this section

```
echo “Place a USB drive into the computer then press the ENTER key” 
read -p "$*" 
sleep 5
```

Clear the USB and reformat it to FAT32 and give it a new name. 
This way the following copy command will work every time.
NOTE /dev/disk2 may be different. Run diskutil list command to check first.

```
diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 462F-0222 /dev/disk2 ; sleep 3
```

Copy command

```
cp -r ~/home/usr/Application/ /media/sid/462F-0222
```

Unmount USB (allows you to safely remove the USB)
NOTE /dev/disk2 may be different. Run diskutil list command to check first.

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
```